# Area of a constrained and bounded strictly non-decreasing function - geometric solution

Tags: euclidean-geometry, area

I have boiled a problem I have down to the following:

Assume a non-decreasing function $pb=f(pt)$, with domain [0,1] and range [0,1].
Require that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$

[image]

Require that from point $A(0,0)$ to point $C(1,1)$ this non-decreasing function must be constrained in the parallelogram $ABCD$ for any $b$,  $0≤b≤1$.

I want to show that the $|area|$ between the function and the line $AC$ is at most $0.5*(1-b)$.

The problem is trivial if the function while traversing from point A to point C remains entirely either within $ABC$ or $ADC$. But what happens if the function crosses the line $AC$ (this is allowed since the function can have $f'(pt)=0)$? How can I show that the $|area|$ between the function and the line AC is also in this case at most $0.5(1-b)$.

Comment: "strictly non-decreasing"?? What is wrong with just saying "increasing"?

Comment: increasing implies $f'(pt)>0$. Strictly non-decreasing implies $f'(pt)\geq 0 $

Comment: There are two common terminologies here: (1) "increasing (decreasing)" means $f' \ge 0 (f' \le 0)$, Adding "strictly" mean $f' > 0 (f' < 0)$. (2) "increasing (decreasing)" means $f' > 0 (f' < 0)$. And "non-decreasing (non-increasing)" means $f' \ge 0 (f' \le 0)$. Because sometimes people speak to audiences without having established which terminology is being used, occasionally you see the amalgam "strictly increasing/strictly decreasing/non-decreasing/non-increasing". But "strictly non-decreasing" is pulling the worst from both worlds.

Comment: In your case, if you interpret "increasing" as $f' > 0$, then surely "decreasing" is $f' < 0$, so "non-decreasing" by itself means $f' \ge 0$. "Strictly" means that the case $f' = 0$ is not allowed. so "strictly non-decreasing" should mean $f' > 0$ again - i.e., "increasing".

Comment: I understand and I have corrected this in the question, thank you. Any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: A number of them, but so far, none successful.at either proving or disproving the result.

Comment: I have been thinking on this problem for quite a while, so far unsuccessfully. The trivial cases are I think quite clear. In the non-trivial case where the function crosses the AC line, it would suffice to show that when you cross for example from ACB to ACD, what you leave behind (and not transverse) in ACB is more than what you will gain in ACD. However I don't know how to formulate it and prove it.